# How to show dialog in page2 after navigation if command button in page1 is pressed?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using commandbutton in page1. If commandbutton is pressed, flow goes to page2. I would like to show a dialog in page2 only if the commandbutton in page1 is pressed (and thus not if page2 is opened directly). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `visible` attribute. The EL expression must evaluate to a `boolean`.

E.g.

```
<p:dialog ... visible="#{bean.page1CommandButtonClicked}">
```